# Extraer numeros con este formato 999-999 999 que contenga una celda Spreadsheet

Tags: regex, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Agradeceria me puedan ayudar con este problema de extraer numeros en planilla de Google, paso a explicar mi caso:

En la celda D4 tengo el siguiente texto:

```
Cargo Terminal de la AWB N° 045-4074 1046 045-4074 1282 698.500 698.500 0 Tipo de Cambio(BCP): 6.992 gs
```

Y necesito extraer los numeros:

```
045-4074 1046 
045-4074 1282
```

Esta es la expresion regular que pude hacer:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(D4;"([\d]{2,3}-[\d]{3,4}[\s]*[\d]{3,4}\s)+")
```

Pero solo obtengo el primer numero 045-4074 1046

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al usar paréntesis estás creando un grupo, que va a ser el valor devuelto por `REGEXTRACT`. Y al repetir ese grupo con `(`...`)+` el valor capturado se **sobreescribe**.

Para agrupar sin generar un grupo se usa `(?:`...`)+`

Así te devuelve todas las coincidencias consecutivas

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(D4;"(?:\d{2,3}-\d{3,4}\s*\d{3,4}\s)+")
```

```
045-4074 1046 045-4074 1282
```

De esta forma no genera una captura pero te permite una "especie de loop" que coincide con todo lo consecutivo que siga coincidiendo con el patrón del regex.

---

Por otro lado, si quisieras cada resultado en una celda diferente, `REGEXTRACT` no te lo permite, así que hay que ir con algunas fórmulas más entreveradas para separarlo. La que se me ocurre ahora es:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(D4;".*?(\d{2,3}-\d{3,4}\s*\d{3,4}\s)|.*";"$1|");"|"))
```

```
045-4074 1046 
045-4074 1282
```

que básicamente usamos el mismo regex, pero esta vez para reemplazarlo por el texto que coincidió seguido de `|`, o con todo el texto si no encuentra más coincidencias... y luego hacemos un `split` para que sea una fórmula matricial y se expanda hacia abajo (gracias al `transpose`) con cada resultado.

(pero debe haber varias formas similares de obtener lo mismo)